# Load PNG and read pixels in PHP without GD?

Tags: php, png, gd

I have a need to read in the exact unaltered pixel data (ARGB) from a truecolour PNG file, preferably from PHP.

Unfortunately the GD library in PHP messes with the alpha channel (reducing it from 8-bit to 7-bit), making it unusable.

I'm currently assuming that my options are either:

1. <strike>Implement my own raw PNG reader to extract the necessary data.</strike>
2. Use some less-broken language/library and call it from the PHP as a shell process or CGI.

I'd be interested to hear any other ideas, though, or recommendations for one way over the other...

**Edit**: I think #1 is out.  I've tried passing the IDAT data stream to gzinflate(), but it just gives me a data error.  (Doing the exact same thing, with the exact same data, outside of PHP produces the expected result.)

Comment: #1 should be out. Installing ImageMagick could be easier. That being said, PNG is an easier format than, say, JPEG.

Comment: implement a PNG reader will be too slow for almost everything you would like to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

How about ImageMagick?

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick("foo.png");
$it = $im->getPixelIterator();

foreach($it as $row => $pixels) {
    foreach ($pixels as $column => $pixel) {
        // Do something with $pixel
    }

    $it->syncIterator();
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with PHP4 at the moment, and ImageMagick is not installed on the server (nor does it appear to be compatible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pngtopnm function of [netpbm](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pnmtopng.html) to convert the PNG to an easily parsed PNM.  Here is a somewhat naive php script that should help you get what you need:

```
<?php
$pngFilePath = 'template.png';
// Get the raw results of the png to pnm conversion
$contents = shell_exec("pngtopnm $pngFilePath");
// Break the raw results into lines
//  0: P6
//  1: <WIDTH> <HEIGHT>
//  2: 255
//  3: <BINARY RGB DATA>
$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $contents);

// Ensure that there are exactly 4 lines of data
if(count($lines) != 4)
    die("Unexpected results from pngtopnm.");

// Check that the first line is correct
$type = $lines[0];
if($type != 'P6')
    die("Unexpected pnm file header.");

// Get the width and height (in an array)
$dimensions = preg_split('/ /', $lines[1]);

// Get the data and convert it to an array of RGB bytes
$data = $lines[3];
$bytes = unpack('C*', $data);

print_r($bytes);
?>
```

Comment: Sadly, this was on a hosted site, so I couldn't add additional software (if I could, I would have installed ImageMagick).  As it happens though this whole thing ended up no longer being required, so it ended up being moot.  But thanks for the answer anyway!  (Although, if that's RGB and not ARGB then it wouldn't have helped.)